# unknown field "annotations" in io.k8s.api.storage.v1.StorageClass - Terraform Helm Chart installation

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

Question:
**How to force terraform installation with unknown field addnotations?**

Description of problem:

There is created helm chart to create storageClass.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-path
{{- if .Values.storageClass.defaultClass }}
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
{{- end }}
provisioner: rancher.io/local-path
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

and in values.yaml are lines:

```
storageClass:
  defaultClass: true
```

When installation of this chart is performed using

```
helm install
```

it install this chart with no problem and with desired values.

Problem apear during terraform installation:

```
resource "helm_release" "storageClassHELM" {
  name       = "storageClassHELM"
  repository = "http://privaterepo:8080"
  chart      = "storageClassHELM"
  version = "0.1.0"

  values = [
    file("${path.module}/values/storageClassHELM.yaml")
  ]
}
```

After terraform apply this is prompt:

```
module.config.helm_release.storageClassHelm: Creating...
╷
│ Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(StorageClass): unknown field "annotations" in io.k8s.api.storage.v1.StorageClass
│ 
│   with module.config.helm_release.storageClassHELM,
│   on config/local-path-provisioner.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "storageClassHELM":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "storageClassHELM" {
```

Question again:
**How to force terraform installation with unknown field addnotations?**

Comment: Can you elaborate how are you using the module you are referencing? Is the `values.yml` file in that module code or outside it?

Comment: It is separate file. This values.yaml is only for terraform deploy of this one module.

During helm install command installation there is also pointing to values file of course.

Comment: No, I meant is the file at the same level as the module or you are providing it at the root module level when calling the config module?

Comment: From root module I called module "config" and pointing to ./config (using source), in config folder I have storageClassHELM.tf file and folder called values for this *.tf file.
Is it answer for your question?